# Flex:How to prompt an alert before navigating to any other page

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

How to ask user confirmation before highlighting/navigating to another panel/page?

I have few panels in my screen. Each panel has many controls. I would like to prompt a message box(or alert) with Ok and Cancel buttons, and take confirmation whenever user clicks on another panel.

If user clicks on "Ok" button  then navigate to another panel/page.
If user clicks on "Cancel" button then remove the alert and focus to the same Panel.

Currently I have implemented this using panel's focus_out event(focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent)). I click on the button which is in the another panel, now I got alert, but when i clicked on "OK" in the alert , nothing is happening(button click is event is not fired)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste some sample code... which parent container you are using ex:-- ViewStack, tabnavigator ...etc..

Comment: Top most parent element is VGroup. It has elements like HGroup, Tab navigator, Panels.

Comment: Create sample and paste ... than only we can help...

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you want to react depending on which button on the alert is clicked?

If that is the case, use the in-built close handler in the [Alert class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html).

The Alert class has a static method show, with the following signature:

```
public static function show(text:String = "", title:String = "", flags:uint = 0x4, parent:Sprite = null, closeHandler:Function = null, iconClass:Class = null, defaultButtonFlag:uint = 0x4, moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):Alert
```

By adding two flags with the pipe operator in the `flags` argument

`Alert.OK || Alert.CANCEL` and then adding your close handler in the `closeHandler` argument, you can inspect which button was clicked and react accordingly.

Something like this:

Alert:
`Alert.show("Alert Title","Would you like to proceed?",Alert.OK || Alert.CANCEL,this,onClose)`

onClose Function:

```
private function onClose(event:CloseEvent)
{
    if (eventObj.detail==Alert.OK) 
    {
      //proceed
    }
    else
    {
      //cancel operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here we need to identify the Button/Controls in another container on which user clicked. But from your example we can identify the which button has been clicked on Alert window(Ok or Cancel button)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on James post here i am posting sample, not sure if you are looking for the same: - Hope below code may give you some idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

            private var storeNextFocusID:String = "first";
            private var storePreviousFocusID:String = "first";

            private function firstFocus():void
            {
                first.setFocus();   
                storePreviousFocusID = first.name;
            }

            private function showFirstTimeAlert(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(event.currentTarget.name != storePreviousFocusID)
                {
                    Alert.show("Do you want to change Tab?","Alert",Alert.OK|Alert.CANCEL,null,closeHandler)
                    storeNextFocusID = event.currentTarget.name;
                }
            }

            private function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
            {
                if(event.detail == Alert.OK)
                {
                    var focusCont:HGroup = mainContainer.getChildByName(storeNextFocusID) as HGroup;
                    focusCont.setFocus();
                    storePreviousFocusID = storeNextFocusID;
                } else
                {

                } 
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup id="mainContainer" x="50" y="50" width="400" height="300" creationComplete="firstFocus()">
        <s:HGroup  id="first" name="first" width="100%" height="100%" click="showFirstTimeAlert(event)">
            <mx:TabNavigator  width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:VBox label="left">
                    <mx:Label text="labelPlacement = 'left'" />
                </mx:VBox>
                <mx:VBox label="right">
                    <mx:Label text="labelPlacement = 'right'" />
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:TabNavigator>
            <s:Panel  width="100%" height="100%">
            </s:Panel>
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup  id="second" name="second" width="100%" height="100%"  click="showFirstTimeAlert(event)">
            <mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:VBox label="top">
                    <mx:Label text="labelPlacement = 'top'" />
                </mx:VBox>
                <mx:VBox label="bottom">
                    <mx:Label text="labelPlacement = 'bottom'" />
                </mx:VBox>
            </mx:TabNavigator>
            <s:Panel  width="100%" height="100%">
            </s:Panel>
        </s:HGroup>

    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```